# Fast way to and rows to dataframe based on number of column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df1 = structure(c(3, 5, 8, 6), .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```

I would like to add 3 rows:

```
(0,0)
(5,0)
(0,8)
```

i.e. for each column, I add a row that is the max of this column, the rest are zeros, and an all zero line. Any fast way to do this?

Comment: Can you do `rbind(df1, cbind(c(0, 5, 0), c(0, 0, 8)))`

Comment: Of course, but I need a generalised way because it will apply to other data frames, and of higher dimension (5).

Comment: Is it the same values you are adding, then create a function

Comment: The structure shows a `matrix`.  Do you have matrix or data.frame

Comment: a data frame. I am checking your solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `colMaxs` from `matrixStats`, get the `diag` and `rbind` with the original matrix along with a 0 padded row

```
library(matrixStats)
rbind(df1, 0, diag(colMaxs(df1)))
```

---

If it is a `data.frame` (based on the title)

```
library(dplyr)    
df2 %>% 
   summarise_all(max) %>%
   diag %>% 
   rbind(df2, 0, .)
```

#### data

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```